# Rails render head vs. status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, http-status-codes

What's the difference between `render head :ok` vs. `render status :ok` in Rails? They both get returned as the header right?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is no difference really. The [Rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses) says this about `head`:

> The head method can be used to send responses with only headers to the
>   browser. The head method accepts a number or symbol (see reference
>   table) representing an HTTP status code

`head :ok` sets render to return just the header with status 200.

It's merely a shorthand for `render nothing: true, status: :ok`.

Rails 5 will also do `head :no_content` by default when you don't have a template defined for an action

Comment: so `render status :ok` is more versatile because it can be used as an option too right?

Comment: I would say more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

The answer used to work for me, but I tried it recently and got a no template error. This is what I use now

`render plain: :success`

It does not answer the question, but the answers don't work.